# Filepath changing while executing sql query from c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

I have a sql database where i am string filepath and file name of some files. I am using Visual Studio 2008 as IDE and SQL Server 2005 for development.

If I am trying to execute a SQL query to get filepath it returns correct result. But when I am executing SQL query from windows application in c#, it is returning Filepath in which all `\` are changed to `//`.

Here is the SQL query I executed from SQL Server Management Studio:

```
select FilePath FROM dbo.[tbl_name] WHERE SerialNo = 2;
```

It results in `FilePath` being `C:\Program Files\Test\Mydoc.pdf`

But when I am trying through C# windows forms code as mentioned below. I am getting a wrong value for `FilePath`:  `C://Program Files//Test//Mydoc.pdf`

```
try
{
     using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
          connection.Open();
          using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT FilePath FROM dbo.[tbl_name] WHERE SerialNo LIKE @Sno", connection))
          {
              command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Sno", Serial));
              FiletoOpen = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
              Process.Start(FiletoOpen );
          }
      }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Exception has occured!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
finally
{
      connection.Close ();
}
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: Why do you consider it as a problem?

Comment: Because it is passing wrong FilePath to Process.start() method,and throwing an exception as System can not find the file specified.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are seeing this path in your debugger. **Debugger is just escaping the path and nothing else**. If you write it somewhere, like console, you will get the original path (with single backslashes).

Comment: Actually I was getting error message as exception, then I tried to debug and found this problem. Exception is coming in process.start(FilePath) line of the code, which means the FilePath it is passing to Process.start() method is incorrect. Suggest any other solution.

Comment: slashed should be \ not /. i thought it was a typing mistake by you.

Comment: Yes, it was typing mistake . I am getting filepath as C:\\Program Files\\Test\\Mydoc.pdf   .  But I am getting correct path using console. Dont know how to resolve it!.

Comment: what is the exception that you are getting?

Comment: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:System can not find the file specified.